# プロフィールのイメージ画像が勝手に変わっていますが何かアナウンスがありましたか？

Tags: バグ

サイトへのユーザー登録時に割り当てられたイメージをそのまま使い続けていましたが、少し前から最初英語版のサイトで変わっていて、今日あたりから日本語版のサイトでも変わっています。
日本語版のMETAも変わっていますが、それが何時変わったかは不明です。英語版のMETAはまだ変わっていません。

不正アクセスされたかどうかは不明です。

以前に1回システムの不具合か何かで変わってしまったこと(たしか複数の人に影響がでていたような？)が記憶にありますが、その時は問題・原因が判明して元に戻ったはずです。
何か変更されるアナウンスがあったのか、システムの不具合なのか、情報があれば教えてください。
その辺が無いとしたら不正アクセスかもしれませんし。
元画像：
[image: 元画像]

新画像：
[image: 新画像]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

恐らく今回は意図的な変更と思われます。MSE にて以下のアナウンスがありました。
(元の画像に戻したい場合には個別に連絡をするように、とも記載されています)

[We're regenerating all identicons - MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389123)

> We've recently discovered a vulnerability in our identicon generation process. To remedy it, we have changed how we approach generating them and regenerated all identicons. We do not have any indication that any personally identifiable information (PII) was leaked as part of this vulnerability.
>
> 最近、ID 生成プロセスの脆弱性を発見しました。これを修正するために、識別アイコンの生成方法を変更し、すべての識別アイコンを再生成しました。この脆弱性の一部として個人を特定できる情報 (PII) が漏洩したという兆候はありません。