# 異なるユーザーで同じプロフィール画像 (identicon) が表示される

Tags: バグ

ユーザーが (任意の) プロフィール画像を設定していない場合、デフォルトでは自動生成された画像が設定されますが、少し前から複数の異なるユーザーで同じ画像が表示されているように見えます。

2023-05 に identicon の表示に関する変更を行っているようなので、この影響だと思われます。

**関連する投稿:**

- [プロフィールのイメージ画像が勝手に変わっていますが何かアナウンスがありましたか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3881)
- [We're regenerating all identicons - MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389123)

**実際の表示:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]